# SASS / SCSS hover when using &__* syntax to reach parent selector

Tags: css, sass, nested, css-selectors, parent-child

Yes yes, I had a hard time trying to define my question.

The general case is like this:
in sass/scss I have a button with some variants:

```
.button {
   /* generic button styles here */
   &__icon {
       color: green;
   }
}
```

And now I wish to use some hover styles on this, per variant. But because I use the &__* I can't seem to grasp how to do this without rewriting the parent class name.

```
.button {
   /* generic button styles here */
   &__icon {
       color: green;
   }
   &:hover {
       .button__icon {
           color: red;
       }
   }
}
```

^^ this works but is pretty manual

Is there a way in sass that allows to access the parent class and get something like:

```
&:hover {
    &__icon {
        color:red;
    }
}
```

But this time the &__icon should reference the parent.

The html to this would look somewhat like this:

```
<button type="button" class="button">
    [name]
    <span class="button__icon">+</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Why not simply do `&__green { color: green; &:hover { color: red; } }`? Also can you add HTML to be safe that we are talking about the same structure?

Comment: Yes you are correct @somethinghere ... I forgot to mention that I also mean the situation when you have an icon that should also change on hover. I'll modify my question to accommodate the extra info

Comment: That is _still_ not an issue, right? The icon is related to the subclass, not the parent really? If you question is 'how do I select the parent' there is no real way to do that in CSS.

Comment: yup, css doesn't have parent selectors. Check my updated question. It's more of a question if sass can interpret the nesting of &:hover { &__icon {} } and for it to reference the parent and not the hover

Comment: It cannot, I have tried this before, but to be honest, that just requires a different approach: give a hover state to your icons, not a icon type to your hovers. The problem with sass is that once you nest it doesn't remember the parent, it remembers the _whole selector_ so how is it supposed to know _which_ of the potential parents you might refer to? I think thats why SASS does not support it. But I would be interested if it existed. I doubt it though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.button {
   $root: &;

   &__icon {
       color: green;
   }

   &:hover #{$root}__icon {
       color: red;
   }
}
```

or

```
.button {
   $root: &;

   &__icon {
       color: green;

       #{$root}:hover & {
           color: red;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Yup this looks nice and it works. thanks @mwl
I would like to write a blog post about this, I will recomend your suggestion in it

Comment: Thanks :) Send me a link!